# How to grab the Tab's URL when the site is opened for the first time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension to block YouTube shorts on the web.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {

    if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/shorts")) {

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {

            type: "NEW"

        });

    }

});
```

This is the background.js which basically checks if the URL contains "shorts", if it does, it sends a message to another JavaScript code which grabs the shorts div and deletes it.

This only works when I scroll the page. I logged the tab's URL when it was loaded for the first time, and it came out to be undefined, therefore it does not enter the "if statement". So if I refresh the page or click on a link, the extension does not work.

Please tell me how I can fix this bug.

I tried using tabs.onCreated.addListener, but the Tab's URL is still blank.

Comment: 1) There's no need for the background script: you can do everything in the content script, either by using MutationObserver that checks the div or via pure `css` that simply hides the div. 2) In tabs.onCreated you should use tab.pendingUrl.

Comment: @wOxxOm tabs.onCreated is not getting triggered when I refresh the page or open a link in the same tab, so I cannot call the code which blocks the shorts div when the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you provide any example or link that shows how to block divs using MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh the page it takes time to load everything.
You need to keep wait page load is not completed.
Use the `changeInfo.status` to check if it's completed or not then check other parameters for URL.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/shorts")) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: "NEW"
        });
    }
});
```

Read more about the [changeInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated#changeinfo_2)

Comment: @darkmatter have you tried this solution ?

Comment: @darkmatter have you tried any of the suggested solutions? If yes please give the feedback :)

Comment: Yes, I tried this, it is not working, I think the "tab" is undefined when it enters the "onUpdated" block and stays like that, or it could be that changeInfo.status is 'loading' and it does not enter the "if block" because of that.